# btrfs subvolume delete /old/opt taking a lot of time and CPU resources, why? what do it about it?

Tags: linux, opensuse, btrfs, delete

The command:

`btrfs subvolume delete /old/opt`

Has been running over night.  Currently 980 minutes and counting, and it is pegging 1 CPU core at 100%.  I also initiated a second delete, and it too is using 100% of 1 CPU core for the last 917 minutes.

The drive is 1 64gb SSD.
OpenSuse Tumbleweeed version dated 9-20-2018
kernel 4.18.8

8gb of RAM

I have over a dozen more to delete.

Can I execute commands before this to make it go faster?

Since the standard command locks a whole CPU core at 100% how do I delete them?

How do I diagnose the problem?

```
libbtrfs0-4.17.1-1.2.x86_64
btrfsmaintenance-0.4.1-2.1.noarch
btrfsprogs-4.17.1-1.2.x86_64
libudisks2-0_btrfs-2.7.6-3.2.x86_64
libbd_btrfs2-2.18-1.1.x86_64
btrfsprogs-udev-rules-4.17.1-1.2.noarch
```

Comment: Which version of `btrfs-progs` are you using?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have added my version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently its to dumb to know that the file system is still mounted.

Instead of failing, and saying it can't do it because the volume is mounted it just hangs.

Worst, apparently, it does delete the contents of subvolume so when you reboot it goes into emergency mode.

You have to edit /etc/fstab to delete the subvolume(s) and then reboot.

Now you can delete the subvolumes normally.